# How to add a button in every tweet on Twitter timeline via a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I want to dynamically add a button in DOM of Twitter timeline such that there will be one button for each tweet.
How can this be done?
I have created a div using `document.createElement("div")`
Now, how will I make it append to every tweet?

Answer (score 2):

You're asking us to do the whole work for you. But a brief tip, fetch the class of tweets and then append the element to that div and use CSS to position it.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Chrome extension that adds a button to every tweet on a Twitter timeline involves several steps. Here's a high-level overview:

1. Create a new directory for your Chrome extension.
2. Create a manifest.json file in the directory. This file provides important information about your extension to Chrome.
3. Create a content.js file. This is where you'll write the JavaScript code that manipulates the DOM of the Twitter page.
4. Write code in content.js that adds a button to every tweet.
5. Load your extension into Chrome and test it on Twitter.

Here's a simple example of how you might implement this:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Twitter Button Adder",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["https://twitter.com/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://twitter.com/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

content.js

```
// Wait for the DOM to load
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Get all tweets
  var tweets = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid="tweet"]');
  
  // Loop through each tweet
  tweets.forEach(function(tweet) {
    // Create a new button
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = 'My Button';
    
    // Append the button to the tweet
    tweet.appendChild(button);
  });
});
```

To load your extension into Chrome:

1. Open Chrome and navigate to chrome://extensions.
2. Enable Developer mode by clicking the toggle switch at the top right.
3. Click the Load unpacked button and select your extension directory.

Now, when you navigate to Twitter, you should see your button added to every tweet. Note that this is a very basic example and may not work perfectly due to the dynamic nature of Twitter's DOM. You may need to use MutationObserver to handle newly loaded tweets.